# Theory behind parallel battery with diode

Tags: batteries, diodes, parallel

In a big simplification of my circuit, will be a situation that capacitor will have more voltage than the main battery. And thus, need a diode protection.

In the current simulation with multsim, this is simple ignored OR I maybe wrongly simulating.

My leader said "until capacitor's voltage is high than main source, so it will flow current and battery no."

My question where is it in theory? Do KVL answer it?

*sorry for my bad english

[image: ckt]

EDIT:

I think this is the more apropriated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All batteries have ESR as well as ultra caps the diode is unnecessary as shown.  Even the diode has ESR when forward biased. These Effective Series Resistance limit current from the V difference across them.

A useful method is to use Diode “OR” common cathode to the load with anode on usable sources.

ESR is not a simple R and each part has a custom way to measure it accurately . Simple way is it’s short circuit current which changes in time.

### edit

From your edit, you now have the Diode "OR" logic diode switch for the Load so that the higher battery source voltage drives the load using Common Cathode(-).

The Charger charges the battery voltage with more current on the one with the lower voltage until equal using Diode "AND" logic using "Common Anode"

This is also called a "Battery Isolator" that prevents a mismatch voltage from shorting each other out. Unfortunately the voltage drop is significant and this is performed better with Power MOSFET  switches.

Here is a [simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%2012%200.0000049999999999999996%208.281975887399955%2035%2050%2050%0Ar%20272%20192%20272%20176%200%200.01%0Av%20272%20176%20272%20128%200%200%2040%2012%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20272%20128%20192%20128%202%0Aw%20368%20128%20464%20128%202%0Av%20368%20176%20368%20128%200%200%2040%2012.5%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20368%20176%20368%20192%200%200.01%0Aw%20320%20192%20272%20192%200%0Ad%20272%2096%20272%20128%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20368%2096%20368%20128%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20272%20128%20320%20128%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20368%20128%20320%20128%201%200.805904783%0Ar%20320%20128%20320%20192%200%2012%0Aw%20368%2096%20320%2096%200%0Aw%20272%2096%20320%2096%200%0Aw%20368%20192%20320%20192%200%0Ag%20320%20192%20320%20208%200%0Aw%20320%2064%20320%2096%200%0Aw%20320%2064%20560%2064%200%0Aw%20272%20176%20192%20176%202%0Aw%20448%20176%20368%20176%202%0A172%20560%2064%20592%2064%200%206%2013.18%2014%2012%200%200.5%20Voltage%0Ar%20192%20128%20192%20176%200%20100%0Ax%20363%20213%20388%20216%204%2012%20ESR%0Ax%20171%2044%20540%2047%204%2012%202%5CsBatteries%5Cswith%5Csdifferent%5Cscharge%5Cslevels%5Csand%5CsVariable%5CsVoltage%5CsCharger%0Ao%207%2064%200%204353%205%2051.2%200%202%207%203%0Ao%209%2064%200%204353%205%200.05%201%202%209%203%0Ao%2010%2064%200%204353%205%201.6%202%202%2010%203%0Ao%208%2064%200%204353%205%201.6%203%202%208%203%0A) you can interact with.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/ya4axeyg  did you adjust anything?  right mouse gives options. You can add parts, drag and duplicate etc.  All passives are ideal unless you add ESR

Comment: I did nothing! Thx

Comment: too bad .. play with it by learning the adjustments, drag and drop undo and redo

Answer (score 1):

The battery model in most simulators (I don't use Multisim) is not really a battery, it's an ideal voltage source. So this circuit will simply very quickly discharge the capacitor to 48.7 V through the ideal source.

If it were a real battery, the current flowing into its cathode could conceivably damage the battery, depending on the battery chemistry and various other factors.

It seems likely that you really should arrange your "protection diodes" to protect the battery from reverse current, rather than the capacitor.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. A trigger is the best solution for protect? Do you have any suggestion how I could protect from reverse current?

Comment: http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/parallel.batteries.pdf

maybe it?

Comment: Yes , but this is old school, with better quality matching people will put in parallel without diodes to avoid the losses and then monitor current using ground strap mV drop to check for bad battery not sharing current,.

Answer (score 0):

If it were not for diode D2 capacitor C1 would be discharged by R1 (and D1) in the absence of battery Voltage.
If D2 is not light emitting diode I see no reason for it's existence.
C1 is an uncommonly huge capacitor.